# Can't style <a> tag in WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, hook

I'm hooking into an action and adding some HTML to the function, but I can't seem to be able to style the 'a' tag like I want to. I'm trying to create a clickable button, and so I thought I'd just make it a link and then style it with CSS, but I can't get my CSS to target the  tag.

Here's the HTML:

```
echo '<a href="www.casthorndesigns.com/wp-login.php?action=register" class="reg_btn">Register/Login</a>';
```

And the CSS:

```
.reg_btn a{
   -webkit-appearance: button;
   -moz-appearance: button;
   appearance: button;
   width: 200px;
   height: 45px;
   border: 2px solid #000;
   background-color: #fff;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #000 !important;
}

.reg_btn a:hover{
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

Is the default theme's 'a' tag just overriding my code? I even tried !important out of desperation and couldn't get it to work. Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use just name of the class in your CSS code, like this:

```
.reg_btn {
   -webkit-appearance: button;
   -moz-appearance: button;
   appearance: button;
   width: 200px;
   height: 45px;
   border: 2px solid #000;
   background-color: #fff;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #000 !important;
}

.reg_btn:hover{
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `a` from your selector.
`.reg_btn` is already a class of the element in question and sufficient enough to target with that selector alone.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is targeting an anchor element within the class reg_btn.

Move the 'a' to the beginning of the selector or remove it entirely.

```
a.reg_btn { }
```

or

```
.reg_btn { }
```